# How to make a Javascript countdown timer which doesnt refresh on page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am creating a Auction website , but i am not being able to formulate a way of how to make the countdown timer fixed for all users.I tried to use Ajax but it was hardly of any help.I am uploading my code here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
    <style>
    body 
    {
    background-image:url('s.png');
    background-size: 1370px 652px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    div.padding {
        padding-top: 270px;
        padding-bottom: 125px;
        padding-right: 50px;
        padding-left: 170px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>


    <div class="padding">


    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","rocauction_db");
    $x=$_POST["serial"];
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM playerdb Where Serial=$x");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

        echo " <b> Name: </b>" . $row['name'] ;
        echo "<br>";
        echo " <b> Score: </b>" . $row['score'] ;
        echo "<br>";
        echo " <b> Link: </b>" . $row['link'] ;
        echo "<br>";
        echo " <b> Price: </b>" . $row['price'] ;
        echo "<br>";    
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>

    Bid: <input type="text" style="width: 30px" disabled id="mybid" name="" value="" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) myFunction();secon(1);">
    <p id="demo" >No Bids Available</p>
    <p id="count" ></p>

    <script>
    var txt="";
    function myFunction()
    {
    txt="";
    var x = document.getElementById("mybid");
    txt=x.value;
    txt=parseInt(txt);
    txt=txt+20;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="<b>Current bid : </b>"+txt+"m";
    }

    var second=60;
    var minutes;
    function secon(check) 
    {   
    if(check==1){
     second=60;
    }
        minutes=Math.floor(second/60);
        var seconde = second - minutes * 60;
        if(seconde<10)
                document.getElementById('count').innerHTML =  "<b>Time Remaining : </b>"+minutes +"<b>:</b>0" +seconde;
        else
            document.getElementById('count').innerHTML =  "<b>Time Remaining : </b>"+minutes +"<b>:</b>" +seconde;
        if (second == 0 && minutes == 0) 
        {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer1); 
        document.getElementById("mybid").disabled = true;
        if(txt=="")
            document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = "<b>Unsold!!!</b>";
        else
            document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = "<b>Sold for : </b>"+txt+"m";
        }   
        else
        {
                second--;
            }
    }
    var countdownTimer1 = setInterval('secon()', 1000);

    </script>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why not calculate time left to Future time on every load. That way you eliminate the need to remember the timer.

Answer (score 1):

You say you require it to stay on page refresh, if it doesnt need to stay for prolonged periods perhaps server php isnt needed, how about html5 local storage?

```
$('document').ready(function(){
                start = 1000;
                timer = localStorage.timer ? localStorage.timer : start;

                setInterval(function(){
                    console.log(timer--);
                    localStorage.setItem("timer",timer);
                },1000);
            });
```

This will check if a value is stored in local storage if not it will start the timer from the start specified.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent a user from refreshing the site or a single element of it, but maybe you can achieve something in your desired direction by using

```
window.onbeforeunload
```

?

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery count down timer , but while the page refresh you can set current time so that we wont miss the time gap

please see here for help : http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to set time remaining in your `session`, so that you will get exact time remaining. and in between you need to re-set time remaining  as per current time.

My PHP Code :

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");

$oldtime = $_session['start_time'];
$newtime = time();
$difference = $newtime - $oldtime;
$time_remaining = $_session['time_remaining'] -  $difference;

$_session['time_remaining'] =$time_remaining;

if ($_session['time_remaining'] > 0)
{ 
    $_session['start_time'] =$newtime;
}
else
{
    //'end_of_time';
}
```

JavaScript :

```
    var seconds = <?php echo $_session['time_remaining']?>;
    function secondPassed()
    {
        var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
        var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
        if (remainingSeconds < 10)
        {
            remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;  
        }
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;

        if (seconds == 0 || seconds<0)
        {
            clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        }
        else
        {
            seconds--;
        }
    }
    var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
```